# Claim: In every graph with at least 2 vertices you can always find 2 vertices with the same degree

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

This appeared as an excercise in my problem sheet at uni. How can this be true for any graph? Ive added a pic of a graph which fails. I've put the degree above the vertex. I did this on powerpoint- dont know any other way only blue dots are vertices. The apex which looks like a vertex is there only because I didnt know to do curves. So the degree sequence is (1,2,3) [image]

I however have proved the claim for simple graphs where there is at most one edges between two vertices. Did the lecturer mean simple graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the claim is true only for simple graphs, which limits the possibilities for what the degree of a node in a graph of a given size can be.

It is quite common for "graph" to implicitly mean "simple graph". The most widespread convention is that if you want to speak about multigraphs you need to say so explicitly.